# Retornar valores para Forms dinâmicos em Delphi

Tags: delphi

Pretendo criar uma quantidade de instâncias ilimitada do frmPai (MDI) que é criado dinamicamente da seguinte forma:

```
class procedure TfrmPai.ShowForm;
var
  frmPai: TfrmPai;
begin
  frmPai := TfrmPai.Create(nil);

  frmPai.Show;
end;
```

Ao fechar executo:

```
procedure TfrmPai.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin   
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Esse `form` possui um botão que chama o `frmFilho` para fazer processamento e exibir um *progress bar*.
Para criar o `frmFilho`, é pedido uma *procedure* de *callback* para notificar ao `frmPai` que o processamento terminou e exibir o resultado

*Callback* do `frmPai`:

```
procedure TfrmPai.MyCallback(icont_process: Integer);
begin
  Self.LabelResultado.Caption := IntToStr(icont_process)+' itens processados.');
end;
```

Criação do `frmFilho`:

```
class procedure TfrmFilho.ShowForm(AMyCallback: TMyCallback);
var
  frmFilho: TfrmFilho;
begin
  frmFilho := TfrmFilho.Create(nil);

  with frmFilho do
  begin
    FMyCallback := AMyCallback;

    Show;
  end;
end;
```

O problema ocorre na execução do *Callback*...

Como fazer a verificação se a instância do `frmPai` para qual o resultado deve retornar não foi fechado enquanto o `frmFilho` estava processando, visto que `frmPai` é criado dinamicamente?

Comment: Acredito que o problema esta na criação do Filho, observe que você esta o criando como `nil`. Não deveria passar o nome do "Pai"?

Comment: isso foi intencional... eu precisava que eles pudessem ser independentes, então eu poderia fechar o formPai, porém não nesse caso, não executaria o callback (pois poderia dar access violation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode ter uma propriedade no filho que identifica o pai, e outra no pai que identifica o(s) filho(s). Antes de fechar o pai, percorra os filhos dizendo "que agora estão órfãos" (ajustando a propriedade correspondente para nil). Algo semelhante ao FreeNotification de TComponent.